# VisualStudio .NET Запуск приложения в режиме оффлайн

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Можно ли в VisualStudio сделать профиль отладки так, чтобы приложение запускалось без доступа к интернету? Надо тестить, как ведёт себя приложение в оффлайне, но каждый раз отрубать интернет не охота

Comment: Что за приложение? Можно создать юзера без доступа к инету и от его имени запускать отладку.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/defaultproxy-element-network-settings?redirectedfrom=MSDN Включение и отключение прокси-сервера на уровне конфигурации может помочь, если указать несуществующий прокси на localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить ваше приложение в правила фаервола